# Rails - Implementing a real time console or logger for background tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, console, real-time

I have a couple of rake tasks. I would want to be able to trigger these manually from my Rails admin. So far, this is not a problem. But those tasks contain a lot of `puts` and `prints`, and it would be cool to be able to see these in the browser as they happen.

(I have no problem rewriting the tasks to be run with delayed_job/sidekiq/redis if necessary)

Any idea how this could be achieved?

**Update:**
Idea #1: What about doing `puts` *and* pushing a message to [Faye](http://faye.jcoglan.com/), and just subscribe to a specific channel in the browser? :) I'm going to use Faye soon anyways. Yes, or no? :)

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it may be the best to publish your messages to Faye in a protected channel, and subscribe to that in Faye after starting the job. You may need to start the job using Delayed job or resque to launch the job asynchronously.